# Using sed to replace a multiline nested array with the contents of a file

Tags: bash, awk, replace, sed

Im automatizing a deployment process, and i need a tool to replace parts of a file. The part that i need to replace is something like this:

```
Vari = {
...
}

REPLACEME = {
    'default' = {
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Like you can see, its a nested array (but i know that will only have 1 nested array). I have the code to replace the array in a file, named FILETOREPLACE.txt, and i need to replace the structure REPLACEME with the contents of that file.

With sed, i get a script that locates the structure (it deletes it), but I can not make it replace it with the contents of the file. The sed script is the next:

```
sed '/REPLACEME = {/{:1; /}/!{N; b1}; N; :2; /}/!{N; b2};//d};' settings.py
```

This sed script makes this:

```
'/REPLACEME = {/{      -> It matchs the begining of the array
    :1;                -> Tag to the parents array
    /}/!{              -> If it's not a closing curl brace
        N;             -> Read next
        b1             -> Go back to :1;
    };
    N;                 -> If its the closing curl braces, continue
    :2;                -> Next tag
    /}/!{              -> Again... continue until it finds a closing curl brace
        N;             -> ...
        b2             -> ...
    };
//d};                  -> This deletes the buffer (I have not been able to replace it)
```

So... i would like if anyone can correct my script to replace the match with the content of another file (called FILETOREPLACE.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do:

```
sed '/REPLACEME/rFILETOREPLACE.txt
     /REPLACEME/,/^\}/d' sed.in
```

The first statement inserts the contents of file `FILETOREPLACE.txt` into the stream as soon as `REPLACEME` is found, and the second statements simply deletes everything from `REPLACEME` to the end of that block. Note that I have simplified the deletion by assuming that the block ends at the first line starting with a closing bracket.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Could you explain how this sed works?